# SignalR won't automatically update the CSHTML without refresh

Tags: c#, razor, signalr

I am trying to have a website with a webapi and a signalR whenever new entry is added in the database.

But as the title suggest the new entry won't be added without refreshing the site. Altough it does show the database entry.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TeamManager.Team> GetAllTeams()
    {
        List<TeamManager.Team> Teamlist = new List<TeamManager.Team>();
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "Select * from [Escapehaarlem].[Team]";

        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        SqlDependency.Start(mainconn);

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            //sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlconn.Open();

            sqlcomm.Notification = null;

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(sqlcomm);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Teamlist.Add(new TeamManager.Team()
                    {
                        TeamID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0)),
                        Teamnaam = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                        AantalPersonen = Convert.ToByte(reader.GetValue(2)),
                        Eindtijd = reader.GetValue(3).ToString(),
                        Datum = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(4)),
                    });
                }

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) { reader.Close(); }
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
        return Teamlist;
    }
```

This is the code for the Webapi, this GET function should be shown on the website.

Furthermore this is the code that I used for the site itself the CSHTML:

```
<div id="body">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>Leader Board</h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <h1>
            <span>
                Top Challengers
                @*<img src="Images/goals_256.png" style="width:40px; height:60px;" />*@
            </span>
        </h1>
        <table id="tblRank" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover"></table>
    </section>
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/signalr/hubs")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var rank = $.connection.leaderboardHub;
            rank.client.displayLeaderBoard = function () {
                LoadResult();
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
            LoadResult();
        });

        function LoadResult() {
            var $tbl = $("#tblRank");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://escapehaarlemhighscore.nl/api/game/GetAllteams',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $tbl.empty();
                        $tbl.append('<thead><tr><th>Rank</th><th></th><th></th><th>Best</th><th>Achieved</th></tr></thead>');
                        var rows = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            rows.push('<tbody><tr><td>' + (i + 1).toString() + '</td><td>' + data[i].Teamnaam + '</td><td>' + data[i].AantalPersonen + '</td><td>' + data[i].Eindtijd + '</td><td>' + data[i].Datum + '</td></tr></tbody>');
                        }
                        $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Could some one explain me why the site won't update without a refresh and how to make it possible.

**EDIT**

This is the code I use for the hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace GebruikerService
{
    public class LeaderboardHub : Hub
    {
        public static void Show()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<LeaderboardHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayLeaderBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the startup:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(GebruikerService.Startup))]

namespace GebruikerService
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your hub code as well? you need to call Hub so it can notify all listening clients

Comment: Just added the code as well as the startup.cs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing actual call of Hub from controller method.

just add after reader is closed

```
LeaderboardHub.Show()
```

for better debugging you could add signalR logging by [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I Will try this suggestion! But it is strange because I tried this setup with a local database and local website and everything works Just fine. But when I try it with an online service it just wont work

Comment: let me know it it worked we could investigate further. Try to elimiante out of code issues (is client connected to server Hub? No other JS errors in console? ,...)

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't debug my code because it is uploaded on an online service. Just like I said I tried it with local database and localhost and that worked fine. But when I uploaded it on Plesk (webservice) it won't work anymore.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (), is the error that I receive.

Comment: i guess you dont have access to server logs? 500 means some unhandled exception on server side.

Comment: I thaugt the same so I contacted my provider, they answered the following: We have already grant required permission to the DB and DB user on our shared server. We suggest you check the code with your developer and refer the below documentation for more suggestions to use SignalR:
https://forums.asp.net/t/2077491.aspx?Values+on+SignalR+page+not+updating+unless+the+page+is+manually+refreshed